# Install or use software on Azure Devops Hosted Agent

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-analysis-services

I am new to Azure Devops and hoping this is a simple fix. I have a powershell script that uses Tabular Editor to deploy .bim file to Azure Analyses Services. This works great on my local machine. I have tried to get this working in the devops pipelines with no luck. I haven't found away to install the software on the hosted agent - Question 1) can I install software on a Hosted Agent e.g. on Hosted VS2017.

Failing being able to install software on Microsoft's hosted agent. I checked in the TabularEditor.exe file into the source code  (I know this ins't best practise). The executable file gets put into the build artifact and publishes. Then in the release when my powershell script is called it just hangs, the script gets stuck here. The powershell script reads from a config file and also uses the path to the tabulareditor executable.

The script I am using works fine if you use a self hosted machine assuming the agent has the correct permissions.

I have another Analyses Services script that is ready and works provided Someone creates an XMLA of the model first, then we provide that as an input instead of a .bim file. But this is not quite the automated route I am looking for.

Also I am aware that there is a third party task that does azure analyses services deployment but I want to avoid using that.

In summary I am looking to find out 
1) if I can indeed install software on Microsofts Hosted Agent
2) Should I be able to use the executable in my build artifact instead
3) Is there a better way to deploy Analyses services with a .bim file

I appreciate this is long winded and slightly unique but any insight or information would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run or install tool on hosted agent in VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294430/how-to-run-or-install-tool-on-hosted-agent-in-vsts)